# Adding a custom profile property to My Site

Tags: my-site, my-profile, managed-property

I want to display a custom (profile) property called "Org Unit" in My Site. That property should be mapped to Active Directory.

Is there a direct way in SharePoint 2010 to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can add a new uerprofile property inside the User Profile Service application with the name as "Org Unit" and configure it to with any specific AD property.Also you can configure it as whether to show this in the profile page, allow it as editable etc..

Comment: yes you can do that , but how you can add that custom property to the oob org browser on my site?